# Embedding a swfs with the same class structure

Tags: actionscript-3

Hello I am an Indie programmer that is using flash develop. I am trying to make a AS3 app that holds a collection of games. I tried embedding the swf file (the game) into a program that has a similar class structure. When I run the program it loops every time i try to run the game. Am i going about this wrong or should i go a different route.

Comment: Any feedback, Jordan?  Did my answer now help you?

Comment: Sorry about that yes it did very muc actually. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like many of these classes are in the default package.  If you segregate the two code bases into separate packages then they will no longer interact with each other without your consent.